# Rails server command error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When I run **Rails s** I got this error on my terminal I also set Ruby to 2.3.3 version and typed **bundle**

> .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.16.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in
>   `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while
>   trying to load the gem 'resque'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)

Any suggestion?

I'm using rails 5.0.1

Thanks

Comment: `rm -rf .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.16.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb` and run bundle again

Comment: @Anand I deleted the file, I did bundle again, then Rails s. But no succes...           .rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:133:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/runtime (LoadError)

Comment: try gem update `bundler`

Comment: Doesn't work, got the same output...

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to follow [this steps](https://github.com/resque/resque#installing-resque)

> ## Installing Resque
>
> In a Rack app, as a gem
>
> First install the gem.

```
$ gem install resque
```

> Next include it in your application.

```
require 'resque'
```

> Now start your application:

```
rackup config.ru
```

> That's it! You can now create Resque jobs from within your app.
>
> To start a worker, create a Rakefile in your app's root (or add this to an existing Rakefile):

```
require 'your/app'
require 'resque/tasks'
```

> **If you're using Rails 5.x, include the following in lib/tasks/resque.rake:**

```
require 'resque/tasks'
task 'resque:setup' => :environment
```

> Now:

```
$ QUEUE=* rake resque:work
```

> Alternately you can define a resque:setup hook in your Rakefile if you don't want to load your app every time rake runs.